# Jquery Ajax return 302 error

Tags: jquery, .net, ajax, web-services

I know the error 302 is because i'm getting redirected...

Here's my call in jquery  :

```
    $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'https://url/WebServices/SearchDocuments',
                    data:"{search: " + e.target.value + " }",

                    dataType: "JSON",


                    success: function(data) {
                        GetDocumentSuccess(data[0]);
                    }
                });
```

I see that i'm being logged out of the webService in a way.

But when i'm using this :

```
  var request = WebRequest.Create(url);
        request.Method = "POST";

        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };

        using (var s = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            using (var sw = new StreamWriter(s))
            {
                sw.Write(true); // Write anything. If the post is empty, the distant server throws an error.
            }
        }
```

it's working, i thinks the problem come from not having this:

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };
```

, when i call it directly from jquery

Is this the problem ?

And

Someone know how to make it work with using jquery ajax ?

Comment: Can you post your jQuery code that is failing. Are you sure you are doing a POST to the service not a GET (or PUT,DELETE etc..)

Comment: Here you go i've done the edit

Comment: Is the page you are making this jQuery request from served via HTTP? Can you see in fiddler (or chrome developer tools) what the actual response coming back from the server looks like. Look for possible cross site scripting block?

Comment: No cross site scripting block ... yeah i'm doing the reqest in HTTP.

Comment: I have no response from the developper tool only blank, but i see a redirect to a logout page from the site where the web service is

Comment: If you get no response then you aren't getting redirected. A 302 redirect would be a response from the server. Check the error console in the dev tools. Maybe there is an error with the request before it goes outbound? Do you see the request going outbound in the tools?

Comment: One thing I've noticed is that your dataType should be "json" not "JSON".